# select dropdown option by option value and option group

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have dropdown with option group and its options, from server i'm getting option group id and option value in viewbag. what i want to achive? I want that option to be selected in dropdown on page load using jquery, whose option group id and option value i'm getting in viewbag

```html
<select>
<option value="0">Select Project</option>
<optgroup data-id="1" label="Agile">
<option data-projtype="Agile" value="1">Agile 1</option>
<option data-projtype="Agile" value="2">Agile 2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup data-id="2" label="Waterfall">
<option data-projtype="Waterfall" value="1">Watrfall 1</option>
<option data-projtype="Waterfall" value="2">Waterfall 2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you asking a jquery question or a codebehind as in something like c#?

Comment: yes, i'm using mvc, on page load i'm getting option group id and option value using viewbag

Comment: It would be a good practice to prepand the value with the option group data-id : value="1-1" , value="1-2" , value="2-1" , value="2-2". That way, when returning data to the server, you could easily distinguish the option selected

Comment: how? any example?

Comment: If you using asp.net-mvc then you strongly bind to your model (using `DropDownListFor()`) - the code you have shown has nothing to do with mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [child CSS selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors) and [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors) together. For example, the following code returns inner text of the `option` that belongs to first option group and it' value is equal to `2` and selects one.

```js
var Agile2value = $('optgroup[data-id=1] > [value=2]').attr('selected','selected').text();
console.log(Agile2value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="0">Select Project</option>
<optgroup data-id="1" label="Agile">
<option data-projtype="Agile" value="1">Agile 1</option>
<option data-projtype="Agile" value="2">Agile 2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup data-id="2" label="Waterfall">
<option data-projtype="Waterfall" value="1">Watrfall 1</option>
<option data-projtype="Waterfall" value="2">Waterfall 2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: But i want that option to be selected in dropdown

Comment: @AamirAli , when you get interested option, you could set it' `selected` attribute value to activate the option. See my updated code.